# Reading data off of a cluster

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io

I need help reading data off of the last cluster of a file using `CreateFile()` and then using `ReadFile()`. First I'm stuck with a zero result for my `ReadFile()` because I think I have incorrect permissions set up in `CreateFile()`.

```
/**********CreateFile for volume ********/

        HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;            
            hDevice = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\C:",    
            0,                
            FILE_SHARE_READ | 
            FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL,             
            OPEN_EXISTING,    
            0,                
            NULL);            

        if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    
        {
            wcout << "error at hDevice at CreateFile "<< endl;
            system("pause");
        }

        /******* Read file from the volume *********/
        DWORD nRead;
        TCHAR buff[4096];
        if (BOOL fileFromVol = ReadFile(
            hDevice,
            buff,
            4096,
            &nRead,
            NULL
            ) == 0) {
            cout << "Error with fileFromVol" << "\n\n";
            system("pause");
        }
```

Next, I have all the cluster information and file information I need (file size, last cluster location of the file,# of clusters on disk, cluster size,etc). How do I set the pointer on the volume to start at a specfied cluster location so I can read/write data from it?

Comment: No point trying to set the file pointer until we can read. Also, I rolled back to the original question because your changes made the answers invalid. If you want to add more, add it in addition to the original question. That said, I believe we are there now.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you specify `0` for `dwDesiredAccess`. In order to read the data you should specify `FILE_READ_DATA`.

On top of that I seriously question the use of `TCHAR`. That's appropriate for text when you need to support Windows 9x. On top of not needing to support Windows 9x, the data is not text. Your buffer should be of type `unsigned char`.

Obviously you need the buffer to be a multiple of the cluster size. You've hard coded 4096, but the real code should surely query the cluster size.

When either of these API calls fail, they indicate a failure reason in the last error value. You can obtain that by calling `GetLastError`. When your `ReadFile` fails it will return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

You can seek in the volume by calling `SetFilePointerEx`. Again, you will need to seek to multiples of the cluster size.

```
LARGE_INTEGER dist;
dist.QuadPart = ClusterNum * ClusterSize;
BOOL res = SetFilePointerEx(hFile, dist, nullptr, FILE_BEGIN);
if (!res)
    // handle error
```

If you are reading sequentially that there's no need to set the file pointer. The call to `ReadFile` will advance it automatically.

Comment: I changed the Flag to FILE_READ_DATA but I'm still getting the same error. I hard coded the buffer to 4096 because that is my cluster size should I still change it?

Comment: You code works fine here, once the access is corrected. You still aren't giving us a last error value. Don't try to do this blind.

Comment: I added an extra error handling and my output is `Error with fileFromVol\n\n error_access_denied`

Comment: Also, the SetFilePointerEx looks like exactly what I need. Would I use it between the FileCreate() and the FileRead()?

Comment: After `CreateFile`, the pointer is set to 0. When you read, the pointer is advanced to just past the end of the block you just read. If you read sequentially you never need to set the pointer.

Comment: OK. Now I can see why you still have problems. You have to pass `FILE_READ_DATA` for `dwDesiredAccess`. You are passing the flag to the wrong parameter. You are passing it to `dwFlagsAndAttributes`.

Comment: I changed `dwDesiredAccess` to `FILE_READ_DATA` and `dwFlagsAndAttributes` to 0 but now I am getting an error_access_denied with Createfile

Comment: You must be running elevated to read a volume directly. Add the requireAdministrator manifest. Or for testing use "Run as administrator". Allow me to take this opportunity to warn you not to test this on your system volume. When you make a mistake and call `WriteFile` by accident, you'll destroy the entire volume.

Comment: Btw you are checking for errors well. That's a good lesson learnt from the previous question. It's great when askers learn from advice. You'd be amazed by how many people ignore such advice. Kudos to you.

Comment: So I closed visual studios, right clicked it from and ran as admin. Still gives me the same error but I'm using a work a laptop and I don't have the highest privileges. Would that matter even if it "ran as admin" ? Also is the `dwFlagsAndAttributes` set to 0 correct?

Answer (score 1):

When doing random-access I/O, just don't mess with the file pointer stored in the file handle at all.  Instead, use an `OVERLAPPED` structure and specify the location for each and every I/O operation.

This works even for synchronous I/O (if the file is opened without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`).

Of course, as David mentioned you will get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if you perform operations using a file handle opened without sufficient access.

Comment: What are the advantages of doing it this way synchronously over class SetFilePointerEx?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Fewer function calls.  Independence from non-local state.  Correct operation if the handle is used from more than one thread.